# Stop VSCode from adding redundant headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, entt

I'm working on a C++ project with VSCode and using [entt](https://github.com/skypjack/entt).

In all of the relevant files, I add `#include <entt/entt.hpp>` and this gives me access to everything I need. VSCode keeps adding `#include "entt/entity/fwd.hpp"` I'm using the `clangd` and `Microsoft Intellicode` extensions but I can't find the setting to disable this. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: How is VSCode adding #include statements in your code?

Comment: i don't know, I was hoping someone could tell me lol

Answer (score 5):

need to add `--header-insertion=never` to the clangd arguments in VSCodes settings.

[image]